# Median multiple criteria vba

Tags: excel, vba

I calculated the median with multiple criteria, the calculation is slow I wanted to make it with vba because calculation could be faster.

The exercise which I linked it is just an example. The slow execution is on my real file which contains 11 offers and more than 3 thousands lines.

The formula for the calculation:

```
IFERROR(MEDIAN(IF(($A$2:$A$44=$N$1)*($E$2:$E$44=J$2)*($B$2:$B$44=$I3)*($F$2:$F$44=$M$1);$G$2:$G$44));"")
```

validate with Ctrl + shift + enter
I tried this VBA code but it does not work

```
Sub MEDIAN()

    For Each cell In Range("J3:L9")

        year = Range("m1")
        offer = UCase(Range("n1"))
        month = UCase(Cells(2, cell.Column))
        day = UCase(Cells(cell.Row,9))

        cell.Value = Application.Evaluate("MEDIAN(IF((" & _
          offer & "=R1C14)*(" & _
          day & "=RC9)," & _
          month & "R2C)," & _
          year & "=R1C13)," & _
          C7 & "))")

    Next cell
End Sub
```

the link is : https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8952CE5DAEF23B26!122&authkey=!AK_xvd_-saszoGs&ithint=file%2cxlsx

Comment: VBA is not going to particularly speed up anything without dumping to a variant memory array and processing 'in-memory' then returning the result to the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer of my question, but it's a heavy execution:
I wont give up until to get a speedy one.

Sub MedianePro()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("j3:l9").ClearContents

For Z = 3 To 9

Range("j" & Z).FormulaArray = _

"=IFERROR(MEDIAN(IF((C1=R1C14)*(C5=R2C)*(C2=RC9)*(C6=R1C13),C7)),"""")"

Range("k" & Z).FormulaArray = _

"=IFERROR(MEDIAN(IF((C1=R1C14)*(C5=R2C)*(C2=RC9)*(C6=R1C13),C7)),"""")"

Range("l" & Z).FormulaArray = _

"=IFERROR(MEDIAN(IF((C1=R1C14)*(C5=R2C)*(C2=RC9)*(C6=R1C13),C7)),"""")"

Next Z

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

don't know about speed, but you may try the following

```
Sub MEDIAN()

Range("J3:L9").ClearContents
With Range("J3")
    .FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(MEDIAN(IF(($A$2:$A$44=$N$1)*($F$2:$F$44=$M$1)*($E$2:$E$44=J$2)*($B$2:$B$44=$I3),$G$2:$G$44)),0)"

    .Copy .Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 2)
    .Copy .Offset(1).Resize(6, 3)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much you really saved me